# Advice needed for generating synthetic valence-arousal annotations?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, deep-learning, data-transformation, computer-vision

For developing models on better understanding of visual image advertisements on an emotion perspective, my current dataset is having multi-labelled adjectives. Using an emotion dictionary which contains arousal valence scores for words, I want to map those scores for getting ground truth arousal valence scores for each image advertisement.

The distribution for each adjective on the emotion dictionary is

[image: Arousal Valence Scatter Plot]

Some advertisements represent all happy, sad and irritated sentiment adjectives in single advertisement, which confused me as to how should i use the data i have as effectively as possible to generate one ground truth arousal valence score for each advertisement? Please help me if you can, would want to know suggestions with regards to it and even any possible flaws/problems with it.....

Answer (score 0):

Putting terms together makes a filtered meaning. For example, in the phrase "hard fun" the way fun is moderated is positive, but in "hard friendship" the way friendship is moderated is negative. So, the emotional values of words do not add, it is more of an "and" operation that is, considering words as sets, the intersection of sets ‘A’ and ‘B’ that is the set containing the common elements from both set ‘A’ and set ‘B’. When a message is put together in sentences, it is the meaning of those sentences that contain value, which is not the emotional value of the words themselves as the words interact. Consider word salad, "Halloween, hunger, home,..." It would be a stretch to interpret word salad, and in English (which has a word order sensitive grammar) even if one could take a word salad to be meaningful, that meaning would change if we changed word order, "hunger, home, Halloween,..."

Thus, to do what you want to do, you would have to develop and deploy a mathematical version of semantics. I have given you a hint that such a thing could exist as a variant of classical grammar, but I am not aware of that having been done in practice. Perhaps my colleagues on this site have seen something to this effect.